# Adobe Dreamweaver CC Phonegap Build Service Issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, dreamweaver, phonegap-build

I am trying to use jQuery mobile inside the Adobe Dreamweaver CC and then use phonegap build service to deploy the application to my phone. The issue here is that the Dreamweaver design panel is showing the jQuery Mobile UI but the application APK which is deployed over the phone does not. :(

Please find below the screenshot of Dreamweaver CC with design and code panel.

[image: screenshot of Dreamweaver CC with design and code panel]

Find below the entire index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>jQuery Mobile Web App</title>
<link href="file:///Macintosh%20HD/Applications/Adobe%20Dreamweaver%20CC/Configuration/Third%20Party%20Source%20Code/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.theme-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="file:///Macintosh%20HD/Applications/Adobe%20Dreamweaver%20CC/Configuration/Third%20Party%20Source%20Code/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.accordion.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="file:///Macintosh%20HD/Applications/Adobe%20Dreamweaver%20CC/Configuration/Third%20Party%20Source%20Code/jquery-mobile/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="file:///Macintosh%20HD/Applications/Adobe%20Dreamweaver%20CC/Configuration/Third%20Party%20Source%20Code/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jQueryAssets/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jQueryAssets/jquery-ui-1.9.2.accordion.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page One</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="#page2">Accenture</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Digital</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4">CASF RIA</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page5">Hybrid Applications using PhoneGap</a></li>
        </ul>       
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#page"><label style="color:white; font-weight:bolder">BACK</label></a><h1>ACCENTURE Page</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="selectmenu" class="select">Select Technology Areas:</label>
        <select name="selectmenu" id="selectmenu">
          <option value="option1">Digital</option>
          <option value="option2">Oracle</option>
          <option value="option3">Mobile</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="slider">Value:</label>
        <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="0" min="0" max="100" />
      </div>
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="flipswitch">Option:</label>
        <select name="flipswitch" id="flipswitch" data-role="slider">
          <option value="off">Off</option>
          <option value="on">On</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div data-role="collapsible-set">
        <div data-role="collapsible">
          <h3>Header</h3>
          <p>Content</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
          <h3>Header</h3>
          <p>Content</p>
        </div>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
          <h3>Header</h3>
          <p>Content</p>
        </div>
      </div>




    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page3">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#page"><label style="color:white; font-weight:bolder">BACK</label></a><h1>DIGITAL Page</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   

    <div id="Accordion1">
      <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
      <div>
        <p>Content 1</p>
      </div>
      <h3><a href="#">Section 2</a></h3>
      <div>
        <p>Content 2</p>
      </div>
      <h3><a href="#">Section 3</a></h3>
      <div>
        <p>Content 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
Content </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page4">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#page"><label style="color:white; font-weight:bolder">BACK</label></a><h1>CASF RIA</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <ol data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-split-icon="arrow-d">
        <li><a href="#">
          <h3>Page</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
          <span class="ui-li-count">1</span></a><a href="#">Default</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h3>Page</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
          <span class="ui-li-count">1</span></a><a href="#">Default</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h3>Page</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
          <span class="ui-li-count">1</span></a><a href="#">Default</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h3>Page</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
          <span class="ui-li-count">1</span></a><a href="#">Default</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h3>Page</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
          <span class="ui-li-count">1</span></a><a href="#">Default</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h3>Page</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
          <span class="ui-li-count">1</span></a><a href="#">Default</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h3>Page</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
          <span class="ui-li-count">1</span></a><a href="#">Default</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h3>Page</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
          <span class="ui-li-count">1</span></a><a href="#">Default</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h3>Page</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
          <span class="ui-li-count">1</span></a><a href="#">Default</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
          <h3>Page</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
          <span class="ui-li-count">1</span></a><a href="#">Default</a></li>
      </ol>
Content </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page5">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#page"><label style="color:white; font-weight:bolder">BACK</label></a><h1>HYBRID APPLICATIONS using PhoneGap</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value=""  />
      </div>
Content </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#Accordion1" ).accordion(); 
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how it looks in the mobile devices:

[image: How jQuery Mobile page looks in Mobile.]

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After going through the APK, just found out that Dreamweaver CC has a bug while packaging the APK from Macintosh. The theme CSS files of the jQuery mobile are taken as default Macintosh Hard Drive Path. Hence you need to tweek it a bit to the relative file path.

Macintosh File Path:

```
<link href="file:///Macintosh%20HD/Applications/Adobe%20Dreamweaver%20CC/Configuration/Third%20Party%20Source%20Code/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.theme-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Instead copy the themes to the following folder and use the relative file path:

```
<link href="jQueryAssets/jquery.ui.core.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

It works great :)